# PHP Account Activation Logic

Tags: php

I am writing PHP in order to activate an account of a user......
Code is filtered, sanitized, passwords encrypted, and I've used PDO to store the data....
I have a header redirect once the data is stored, to lead the user to click on an activation link on their registered email address.

Everything was working fine, I was using a PDO RowCount() to tell the redirect to go ahead and run, but I added a hash column in the MySql Database to aid the activation link to then be queried to actually activate the account, so the RowCount was already populated and the redirect would just run bypassing the form itself. So I've written some code to enable the redirect to work, which it does, however it is still bypassing the form itself.....
I need this code to run the header redirect, to say that the database has been populated by the form, but I need it to stop bypassing the form itself and just going ahead and redirecting.

Code below....More code available on request.....

```
   try{
   $checkEmail = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
   $checkEmail->bindParam(':email', $clean['email']);
   $checkEmail->execute();
   $result = $checkEmail->fetch();
   print_r($result);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
   $e->getMessage();
    }
   if ($result[0] === $clean['email']){

           header('Location:verifyemail.php');



     }
```

The $clean['email'] is the current email address, in the programming logic. But it seems the PHP already has some value for this, hence the form is being bypassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be completely misunderstanding the intent of this code snippet, but if when the page first loads, `$clean['email']` is `NULL` (since no form input has been processed), I think that `if` condition will always be true:

1. PDO substitution runs with placeholder substituted for NULL, so equivalent to `SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = NULL`
2. No row is matched (guaranteed, since even `NULL = NULL` is false in SQL)
3. `$result[0]` is undefined, because the SQL query returned no rows
4. therefore, `$result[0]` and `$clean['email']` both evaluate to PHP NULL, and therefore identical
5. redirect fires

[Update, from comment]  I think this approach will work for everything other than NULL input; you just need to detect the case of `$clean['email']` not having been supplied at all. Perhaps `if ( ! empty($clean['email']) && $result[0] === $clean['email'] ) { ... }`

Comment: Yeah so I just need a piece of data to say the database has just been populated rowCount() did that, but once I inserted the hash into the database it just bypassed, as the database was automatically populated at least in one column. I was looking at columnCount() with PDO, but I think the database needs to be queried first. What I need is a PDO method that says x number of columns have literally just been populated, go and redirect.....

Comment: @AntPower I think this approach will work for everything other than NULL input; you just need to detect the case of `$clean['email']` not having been supplied at all. Perhaps `if ( ! empty($clean['email']) && $result[0] === $clean['email'] ) { ... }`

Comment: Gonna try that right now........Thanks....